# ejecutar funcion php cada determinado tiempo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, bucles, timeout

Intento consumir el servicio de una API hasta el momento mi PHP luce así:

```
do {                
      $estadoResponse = CobrosController::paymentStateRequest($channel, $messageId, $clientId, $idTransaccion);//consulta estado de pago.
      $consultaCobro = json_decode($estadoResponse, true);
      $array2 = $consultaCobro['ResponseMessage']['ResponseBody']['any']['getStatusPaymentRS'];
      $respuestaStatus = $array2['status'];//se posiciona en el status

    } while ($respuestaStatus == '33');
```

ahí estaría ejecutando el consumo del API y esperando que la respuesta sea un status '35', este ciclo se cumple correctamente aunque lo que requiero esencialmente es que este proceso sea realizado solo cada 25 segundos, o hasta que el status cambie sea el requerido, este método realiza la petición:

```
public static function paymentStateRequest($channel, $messageId, $clientId, $idTransaccion) {
    $host = "url de la pagina del servicio";
    $servicePath = "/payments/v1/-services-paymentservice-getstatuspayment";
    $body = CobrosController::getBodyPaymentStateRequest($channel, $messageId, $clientId, $idTransaccion);//metodo que arma el cuerpo de la petición consulta
    $response = ApiNequi::makeSignedRequest($host, $servicePath, 'POST', $body); // metodo que envia la peticion con el formato requerido

    if (json_decode($response) == null) 
    {
      return $response;
    }
    else
    {
      $cobroResponse = json_decode($response, true);//decodifica la respuesta que envía la petición a la API
      $array2 = $consultaCobro['ResponseMessage']['ResponseBody']['any']['getStatusPaymentRS'];
      $respuestaStatus = $array2['status'];

 if($respuestaStatus == '35'){

        return $respuestaStatus;
      }
  }
```

si el valor es 33 debe seguir ejecutando esta función hasta que retorne 35, estos valores son enviados a un controlador responseController (), quien los compara y creería es donde debo utilizar un js que realice la consulta y decodifique la respuesta para verificar el numero que recibe, responseController() luce así:

```
public function responseController(){

    $idTransaccion ='123123123';
    $consulta = CobrosController::paymentStateRequest($idTransaccion);

    if($consulta){
      $status = $consulta['status'];

      if($status == '35'){
        return "success";
      }else{
            return "error";// en este caso es donde si es distinto a 35 debe realizar nuevamente el proceso al metodo
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Quizá quien necesita consumir los datos de la API es el cliente cada X tiempo?  Si fuera el servidor lo mejor sería programar un cron en el servidor que te ejecute ese script cada 25 segundos... pero ¿realmente necesitas que ese script cambie de valor constantemente cada 25 segundos sin importar que nadie esté consumiendo esa información? sería algo muy raro y muy descabellado, creo.

Comment: @A.Cedano el servicio debe ser consumido luego de que el usuario ejecute una acción , y este a su vez debe esperar que la respuesta sea un valor distinto a 33, en cuanto sea distinto el servicio termina de ejecutarse, lo he estado analizando y según mi equipo de trabajo sería mejor programarlo de esa manera con un cron, aunque aún no he logrado encontrar la forma correcta de ejecutarlo y pasarle los datos entre js y php, claro que sé que debe ser con un ajax, pero en esto de los servicios aún soy nuevo.

Comment: he encontrado un caso parecido en el cual se presenta como solución el sgte código de js, aunque en mi caso no estaría enviando ningún valor por el metodo POST, ya que le estoy pasando los valores a la función directamente esta manera: `CobrosController::paymentStateRequest($channel, $messageId, $clientId, $idTransaccion)`.

Comment: Este es el ejemplo el cual encontré
`<script>
    $(function() { // Ojo! uso jQuery
        cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
        function cron() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "index.php", // archivo donde se encuentra el cod PHP
                data: {
                    action: 1
                }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            });
        }
        setInterval(function() {
            cron();
        }, 10000); // Lanzará la petición cada 10 segundos
    });
</script>`

Comment: Si es como dices el control del tiempo debe hacerse desde el cliente (o sea desde Javascript) enviando una petición Ajax al servidor cada 25 segundos. El servidor verificaria el valor, devolviendo TRUE cuando sea 35 , recogerias la respuesta en el cliente y mostrarias un mensaje o algo así. Aquí debería haber varios ejemplos parecidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución correcta es ejecutando el setTimeout() desde un ajax y envíando los datos mediante un controlador php que conecta desde el client al servidor, como sugieriern previamente:

```
globalTransaccion = "-1";//variable global
c=1;//variable para conteo

$(document).ready(function()
{   
    if (globalTransaccion != "-1")
       queryNotificationConsulta();//funcion para iniciar la función cuando la variable global cambia su valor
});
```

luego creo el metodo que hará el proceso de verificación:

```
    function temporizadorFuncion()
{
  var i;        
  c++;
  alert("Entrando a Consultar estado :" + c);

  $.ajax({            
    url: "./controllers/consultaEstado.php", //control al que envío parametros y devuelve el valor solicitado
    type: 'POST',
    data: "&idDePeticion="+idDePeticion, //dato solicitado para hacer la consulta
    dataType:"html", // tipo de dato que retorna

  }).done(function(data) { //al completar la petición

        alert(data); 
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        status  = json.status;

        if(status == "1")
        {
           alert("Transaccion Exitosa");
           globalTransaccion = "-1";
        }
        else
        {
           if(status == "2") // Status es 33 en espera de pago y debe volver a consulta en 25s
           {
                   setTimeout('temporizadorFuncion()',25000);
                   console.log("Consultando...");
           }    
           else
            alert("Error en CODE :" + status ); 
        }
  }).fail(function(data) { // si falla la petición
     alert("Error Alert Data: "+ data); 
  });
}
```

archivo *PHP* que recibirá los datos enviados desde ajax a mi controlador (consultaEstado.php):

```
$idPeticion=$_POST["idPeticion"];//variable enviada desde el metodo para la consulta

$control= new ControllerPeticion();//clase de mi controlador que instnacio
$result = $control->StateController($idPeticion); // metodo a quien envío el parametro para la ejecución 

echo '{"status":"'.$result.'"}'; ] // response que retorna desde la petición enviada por medio de *echo*
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias utilizar el `setInterval()` para lograr hacer que controle cada 25 segundos hasta que la respuesta sea 35

ejemplo :

```js
var suma = 0
 var bucle = setInterval(function(){
        suma++;
        console.log(suma);
        if(suma == 5){
            clearInterval(bucle);
        }
    },1000);
```

en este caso para que sea rapido el output le pase como parametro `1000` osea 1 segundo, ya que se tiene que pasar el tiempo en milisegundos, en tu caso seria :

```
var bucle = setInterval(function(){
    //peticion ajax
    if(/*tu condicion */){
        clearInterval(bucle);
    }
},25000);
```

dentro del if, se le pone el `clearInterval()` que sirve para detener el bucle.

esperto te sea de ayuda, exitos

**EDIT**
si lo queres hacer al interno de php :

```
<?php ... ?>
<script>
   var bucle = setInterval(function(){
       // <?php tu codigo php ?> 
       if(/* <?php tu condicion ?>*/){
           clearInterval(bucle);
       }
   },25000);
</script>
```

**EDIT 2**

AJAX :

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "https://tuservidor.com", //url del server al cual le queres hacer la peticion
     type : "GET", // post, get, merge .. tipos de peticiones http
     datatype: "JSON", // formato de la respuesta
     success: function(data){...}, // que hacer si la llamada se ejecuto bien 
     error: function(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
     }  //que hacer si la llamada dio algun error 
 });
```

**EDIT 3**

okay a este punto te diria de recrear la funcion `setInterval()` en php para poder usarlo con mayor tranquilidad :

```
function setInterval($funcion, $millisegundos, $condicion){
    $segundos = (int)$milliseconds/1000;
    while(!$condicion)
    {
        $funcion();
        sleep($segundos);
    }
}
```

para usarlo :

```
setInterval(function(){
   // lo que quieres repetir
}, 25000, $respuestaStatus . " == 35");
```

no la he probado pero tendria que funcionar

Comment: lannarelli saludos , este script lo podría integrar dentro de mi metodo php como se hace normalmente con un -echo-? por ejemplo :

`public function metodo($parametro1, $parametro2){
   
// funciones php a ejecutar y obtener datos para realizar la peticion del consumo

echo '<script>//codigo js para el consumo del servicio</script>';

if ($response == '35'){
 return $response;
}

}`

Comment: podes provar a hacerlo, la verdad no se si funciona, yo te aconsejaria igualmente que hagas como te puse en el ejemplo, abriendo y cerrando `<?php ?>` en las partes donde necesitas el utilizo de php, al final del script podes seguir escribiendo php tranquilamente, simplemente abriendo el tag. haceme saber si te funciona. saludos

Comment: @Federico_lannarelli, ya lo probé pero el script no funciona, entra a la consulta donde se abren las llaves en php pero no realiza el metodo setInterval, tendría que probar ahora con el uso de ajax aunque no estoy muy familiarizado con este, quizá pordrías ayudarme a aclarar la duda sobre las peticiones con ajax.

Comment: lannarelli he intentado aclarar un poco más los metodos que utilizo, quizá de esta manera sea más especifico lo que necesito.